# Pre-order tree traversal and the order of stack pushing

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

Does the order of stack pushing matter in pre-order traversal of trees?

For example, [Iterative Preorder Traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-preorder-traversal/)

In the following source code,

```
void iterativePreorder(node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
 
    stack<node*> nodeStack;
    nodeStack.push(root);
 
    while (nodeStack.empty() == false) 
    {
        struct node* node = nodeStack.top();
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        nodeStack.pop();
 
        if (node->right)//<--------------------------------
            nodeStack.push(node->right);
        if (node->left)//<---------------------------------
            nodeStack.push(node->left);
    }
}
```

if I switch the position of stack-pushing of left and right nodes,

```
void iterativePreorder(node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
 
    stack<node*> nodeStack;
    nodeStack.push(root);
 
    while (nodeStack.empty() == false) 
    {
        struct node* node = nodeStack.top();
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        nodeStack.pop();
 
        if (node->left)//<---------------------------------
            nodeStack.push(node->left);
        if (node->right)//<--------------------------------
            nodeStack.push(node->right);
        
    }
}
```

does it make any difference?

I mean, if the positions are switched, is that still a **proper** pre-order traversal?

Comment: It's called a **reverse** pre-order traversal for reasons which may become obvious when you try it...

Comment: @dratenik, I know the reason. That was not the point of my question.

Comment: There is a difference, it produces a different order. I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @dratenik, your first comment gave me the answer: *It's called a reverse pre-order traversal*. So, the answer to my question is: it will still be a **valid** pre-order traversal, but a special type of pre-order traversal called the **reverse** pre-order traversal.